# How do I get a function to be called when a menu item is clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, menu

In Qt, I have a menubar that looks something like this:

```
|File|
+-------------------+
|Do Something       |
|Do Something Else  |
+-------------------+
```

I have a function `doSomething` that I want to be called when the user clicks on the `Do Something` in the file menu, and a function `doSomethingElse` that I similarly want to be called when the user clicks on that menu item. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, your menu items are `QAction`s.  Connect the QAction signal `triggered()` with the `doSomething()` that you want called.

[This](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html) is a pretty full-fledged description of how this works. But [this section](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/tutorials-addressbook-part2.html) of the [address book tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/tutorials-addressbook.html) is good for a quick explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the function is not part of any class?

Comment: I don't believe so. Slots need to be member functions of a class with the Q_OBJECT macro, if I recall correctly.

Comment: From my first link "All classes that contain signals or slots must mention Q_OBJECT at the top of their declaration. They must also derive (directly or indirectly) from QObject."

Answer (score 2):

Make your function a slot and connect menu action to the slot.